# App generated with PyInstaller does not find files after building for MacOS

Tags: macos, file, pyinstaller

I've created a Mac OS Catalina virtual machine at Oracle VM VirtualBox, and tried to build my application running PyInstaller.

Here is the app.spec file:

```py
# -*- mode: python ; coding: utf-8 -*-

block_cipher = None

added_files = [
        ('resources/data', './resources/data'),
        ('resources/icons', './resources/icons')
]

a = Analysis(['app.py'],
              pathex=['/Users/lavinia/Documents/GraphFilter'],
              binaries=[],
              datas=added_files,
              hiddenimports=[],
              hookspath=[],
              runtime_hooks=[],
              excludes=[],
              win_no_prefer_redirects=False,
              win_private_assemblies=False,
              cipher=block_cipher,
              noarquive=False)
pyz = PYZ(a.pure, a.zipped_data,
         cipher=block_cipher)

exe = EXE(pyz
          a.scripts,
          [],
          exclude_binaries=True,
          name='app',
          debug=False,
          bootloader_ignore_signals=False,
          strip=False,
          upx=True,
          console=False , icon='resources/icons/hexagon.ico')
coll = COLLECT(exe,
               a.binaries,
               a.zipfiles,
               a.datas,
               strip=False,
               upx=True,
               upx_exclude=[],
               name='app')
app = BUNDLE(coll,
             name='app.app'
             icon='resources/icons/hexagon.ico',
             bundle_identifier=None)
```

You can see that in the `added_files` variable I am describing the path for some files that my application requires.

Then I ran:

```
pyinstaller app.spec
```

However, after it finishes building and executing the `app.app` in the *dist* folder, the distribution does not work. Executing from inside the generated folder *app* the executable console application to see if I could find some errors, it prompts that the ["resources/data/data_dictionary.json"](https://user-images.githubusercontent.com/37659479/126854047-621260ec-8ff7-4c64-bc83-951f7f00d02a.png) was not found.

Looking in the folder, I can find the resources folder in the [same folder where the application is](https://user-images.githubusercontent.com/37659479/126853598-2d6d4f62-f9ff-4b37-86f8-f9d34dba949d.png), and the [file is inside the folder](https://user-images.githubusercontent.com/37659479/126854675-cb22012c-7320-45c2-9b4f-0994d3a463e8.png), as expected.

I don't know any ways to debug it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was finally able to generate the app file with the following configurations:

- python3.8.12 installed from pyenv
- pyinstaller 5.0.dev0 installed from dev branch

Then, at the main python file, I added the following:

```py
import os
os.chdir(sys._MEIPASS)
```

> It won't work to execute it locally, but it works with pyinstaller.

I've created a spec file using the following:

```py
pyi-makespec --windowed --add-data "./resources/data:resources/data" --add-data "./resources/icons:resources/icons" --name GraphFilter --onefile --icon ./resources/icons/hexagon.icns app.py
```

Then run pyinstaller:

```py
pyinstaller GraphFilter.py
```

And that's it!