# App generated with py2app throws Module Not Found error for Scipy

Tags: macos, build, scipy, py2app

I've created a Mac OS Catalina virtual machine at Oracle VM VirtualBox, and tried to build my application running py2app.

Here is the setup.py file:

```py
"""
This is a setup.py script generated by py2applet

Usage:
    python setup.py py2app
"""

from setuptools import setup

APP = ['app.py']
DATA_FiLES = [
     'resources'   
]
OPTIONS = {}

setup(
    app=APP,
    data_files=DATA_FILES,
    options={'py2app': OPTIONS},
    setup_requires=['py2app'],
)
```

At first, I ran in alias mode to see if the result works:

```
python setup.py py2app -A
```

and the application works just fine.

However, trying to build the application with the command:

```
python setup.py py2app
```

the resulting application throws an error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<frozen zipimport>", line 259, in load_module
  File "scipy/special/_ufuncs.pyc", line 14, in <module>
  File "scipy/special/_ufuncs.pyc", line 10, in __load
  File "imp.pyc", line 342, in load_dynamic
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 711, in _load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 680, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 1181, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 228, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "_ufuncs.pyx", line 1, in init scipy.special._ufuncs
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'scipy.special._ufuncs_cxx'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/lavinia/Documents/GraphFilter/dist/app.app/Contents/Resources/__boot__.py", line 157, in <module>
    _run()
  File "/Users/lavinia/Documents/GraphFilter/dist/app.app/Contents/Resources/__boot__.py", line 84, in _run
    exec(compile(source, path, "exec"), globals(), globals())
  File "/Users/lavinia/Documents/GraphFilter/dist/app.app/Contents/Resources/app.py", line 3, in <module>
    from source.controller.controller import Controller
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1007, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 986, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 664, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 627, in _load_backward_compatible
  File "<frozen zipimport>", line 259, in load_module
  File "/Users/lavinia/Documents/GraphFilter/dist/app.app/Contents/Resources/lib/python39.zip/source/controller/controller.py", line 1, in <module>
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1007, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 986, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 664, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 627, in _load_backward_compatible
  File "<frozen zipimport>", line 259, in load_module
  File "/Users/lavinia/Documents/GraphFilter/dist/app.app/Contents/Resources/lib/python39.zip/source/controller/welcome_controller.py", line 3, in <module>
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1007, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 986, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 664, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 627, in _load_backward_compatible
  File "<frozen zipimport>", line 259, in load_module
  File "/Users/lavinia/Documents/GraphFilter/dist/app.app/Contents/Resources/lib/python39.zip/source/controller/wizard_controller.py", line 6, in <module>
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1007, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 986, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 664, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 627, in _load_backward_compatible
  File "<frozen zipimport>", line 259, in load_module
  File "/Users/lavinia/Documents/GraphFilter/dist/app.app/Contents/Resources/lib/python39.zip/source/view/wizard/pages/review_page.py", line 2, in <module>
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1007, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 986, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 664, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 627, in _load_backward_compatible
  File "<frozen zipimport>", line 259, in load_module
  File "/Users/lavinia/Documents/GraphFilter/dist/app.app/Contents/Resources/lib/python39.zip/source/domain/utils.py", line 3, in <module>
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1007, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 986, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 664, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 627, in _load_backward_compatible
  File "<frozen zipimport>", line 259, in load_module
  File "networkx/__init__.pyc", line 61, in <module>
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1007, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 986, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 664, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 627, in _load_backward_compatible
  File "<frozen zipimport>", line 259, in load_module
  File "networkx/generators/__init__.pyc", line 8, in <module>
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1007, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 986, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 664, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 627, in _load_backward_compatible
  File "<frozen zipimport>", line 259, in load_module
  File "networkx/generators/community.pyc", line 9, in <module>
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1007, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 986, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 664, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 627, in _load_backward_compatible
  File "<frozen zipimport>", line 259, in load_module
  File "scipy/special/__init__.pyc", line 633, in <module>
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1007, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 986, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 664, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 627, in _load_backward_compatible
  File "<frozen zipimport>", line 261, in load_module
KeyError: 'scipy.special._ufuncs'
2021-07-25 00:29:31.270 app[4178:141143] app Error
Unable to create basic Accelerated OpenGL renderer.
Unable to create basic Accelerated OpenGL renderer.
Core Image is now using the software OpenGL renderer. This will be slow.
```

I don't understand why was not possible to find this module.

Answer (score 0):

Still unresolved，but have some attempts and progress:

1. Reinstall Scipy：pip uninstall scipy,then pip install scipy. error as before.
2. Downgrade python from 3.8 to 3.7, and downgrade py2app from 0.24 to 0.19, new error appeared.
3. Back to python3.8, use Pyinstaller 4.5.1. That's Ok, got a App, but size is 1.35GB.
4. use pipenv create virtual environment, still use Pyinstaller, got a small size APP about 205MB. That's fine for me.

Comment: Hey! Thanks for the answer. I did myself lots of tests as described in this issue I opened in [my project](https://github.com/GraphFilter/GraphFilter/issues/114).

However, I also got a problem using PyInstaller. I've [opened a question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68506523/app-generated-with-pyinstaller-does-not-find-files-after-building-for-macos) about it too. Could you take a look?